# Exact sequence of module sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Bosch's textbook, Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra, he claims, on pages 258-9 in Prop 4 that the functor $M\mapsto\tilde{M}$ from $A$-modules to $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules is exact ($\tilde{M}$ is given by $\tilde{M}(D(f))=M_f$ for distinguished sets $D(f)$).

To do so, in his proof, he remarks that given an exact sequence of $A$-modules $M'\to M \to M''$, "any section of the kernel of $\tilde{M}\to\tilde{M}''$ living on some open subset of $X$ admits local preimages in $\tilde{M}'$. But then it follows that the sequence $\tilde{M}\to \tilde{M}\to \tilde{M}''$ is exact." I don't really understand this part in the quotations -- how exactly does this imply the sequence of module sheaves is exact? In particular, do we not have to be careful about using the sheafification of the image presheaf (which is kinda ugly)?

I think there is another way of proving that the functor is exact (noting that we can look at the stalks instead), but I'd like to understand what Bosch means here.

Comment: This is what he's doing, he's looking at an $s$ in the kernel of $\tilde{M}(U)\to \tilde{M}''(U)$, and he says that such an $s$ doesn't necessarily lie in the image of $\tilde{M}'(U)$, but for every $x\in U$ if we shrink $U$ to a $V_x$ we can find sections of $\tilde{M}'(V_x)$ that will be mapped to $s_{|V_x}$, but that is exactly saying that the sequence is exact on stalks (also, this is not directly used here, but recall that sheafifcation doesn't change stalks so the stalks of the image sheaf is the stalk of the image presheaf).